# WebSocket chat application. From localhost to my domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm learning about node js and Websockets. I created a really simple chat application using some tutorials etc. I'm now running it on a localhost. But how do I put it on my real domain? It's now listing to port 4000 and URL localhost:4000. But I'm don't know what I have to change to let it work on my site. I'm trying to upload my code to my already hosted site. But I don't know what I need te change in my code for that. (that it will work)

```
index.js :

var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

// App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log('listening for requests on port 4000,');
});

// Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Socket setup & pass server
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

    // Handle chat event
    socket.on('chat', function(data){
        // console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });

    // Handle typing event
    socket.on('typing', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
    });

});





chat.js:


// Make connection
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

// Query DOM
var message = document.getElementById('message'),
      handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
      btn = document.getElementById('send'),
      output = document.getElementById('output'),
      feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// Emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
    });
    message.value = "";
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
})

// Listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
});

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>';
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Nunito';
}

h2{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #575ed8;
}

#mario-chat{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#chat-window{
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

#output p{
    padding: 14px 0px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    color: #555;
}

#feedback p{
    color: #aaa;
    padding: 14px 0px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

#output strong{
    color: #575ed8;
}

label{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

input{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #eee;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    font-family: Nunito;
    font-size: 16px;
}

button{
    background: #575ed8;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>WebScockets 101</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
        <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="mario-chat">
            <h2>heavy shit</h2>
            <div id="chat-window">
                <div id="output"></div>
                <div id="feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Handle" />
            <input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
            <button id="send">Send</button>
        </div>


    </body>
    <script src="/chat.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have a domain, but do you have a server to run the program on?

Comment: My server is hosted if you mean that.

Comment: So you have a server that you can run this code on?

Comment: At the moment I'm running the server on localhost:4000 so probably not. But yes I have a working running hosted site so maybe. :)

Comment: But I'm trying to get this script my chat application on my already hosted running site. But I think that I have to change some things in my code for that. But I don't now what.

Comment: Where are you hosting your running site?

Comment: I'm hosting it sith the free turbohost.nl service.

Comment: Does it only host static sites or can you run code on it?

Comment: Normally I upload my code with filezilla on my site that is hosted by turbohost.nl.

Comment: You won't be able to host something like this on that site then.

Comment: how can I fix this what do I need for this?

Comment: You can always try hosting it on heroku.

Comment: I tried to install heroku but if I type git push heroku master I get a error : error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/****.git' can you help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried typing `git pull --rebase` first?

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: @Aplet123 can you help me with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018567/heroku-error-at-error-code-h10-desc-app-crashed-method-get