# heroku error: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, websocket

If I try to open my heroku site I get a application error. If I run heroku logs --tail in the terminal I get a error: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=unidicks.herokuapp.com request_id=32754547-c705-4a11-9364-39a2168f7a71 fwd="84.195.162.123" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https. How can I fix this?

```js
index.js :

var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');


// App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function(){
    console.log('listening for requests on port 4000,');
});

// Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Socket setup & pass server
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

    // Handle chat event
    socket.on('chat', function(data){
        // console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });

    // Handle typing event
    socket.on('typing', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
    });

});
```

procfile:

web: node index.js

```js
package.json:

´{
  "name": "websockets-playlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A chat app using WebSockets",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/iamshaunjp/websockets-playlist.git"
  },
  "author": "The Net Ninja",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/websockets-playlist/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/websockets-playlist#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}`
```